# aggregate function SUM for time values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, time, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to generate ranklist, in which I have to sum many time durations to get total time, when I tried SUM(TIMEDIFF(`finishTime`,'starttime')) in MySQL I noted that addition of two time durations occurs as if they were two normal numbers, ie if I add 00:00:50 and 00:00:50, I get 00:01:00 as answer.

TO_SECOND is not available in MySQL 5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SUM(TIMEDIFF(TIME_TO_SEC(finishtime) - TIME_TO_SEC(starttime)));
```

Use [TIME_TO_SEC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) to convert TIME to seconds for math operation

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think if you're using TIMEDIFF, you can't have a manual subtraction symbol and should use a comma instead -- or get rid of the TIMEDIFF if regular subtraction works.

Answer (score 1):

In the event that you were working with datetime timestamps, I found that I could get more reliable results using the following method:

```
 SUM( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( finishtime ) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP( starttime ) ) /3600
```